# How to send automated emails with hyperlinks using javascript in google sheets

Tags: html, email, google-apps-script

I want to send email containing some text message and hyperlink so the user can click on the link and opens up the URL. But it only display as text when I send. Truly appreciate if anyone can help out.

```jsx
function sendEmails() {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
    var numRows = 10;   // Number of rows to process
    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 4)
    var data = dataRange.getValues();
    for (i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[1];
        var name = row[0];
        var message = row[2];
        var links = <a href="https://www.google.com/">Click here</a>;
        var subject = "Sending emails from a Spreadsheet";
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, links);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app

You are using `sendEmail(String,String,String,String)`, but if you use `sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)` instead, you can use an object with an `htmlBody` property, which will allow HTML.

There's also sendEmail(Object), for which an example is given that has `htmlBody`:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({
  to: "recipient@example.com",
  subject: "Logos",
  htmlBody: "inline Google Logo<img src='cid:googleLogo'> images! <br>" +
            "inline YouTube Logo <img src='cid:youtubeLogo'>",
  inlineImages:
    {
      googleLogo: googleLogoBlob,
      youtubeLogo: youtubeLogoBlob
    }
});
```

---

You said you've managed to send text emails, so I'm taking it from there. I'm going to assume that you want the following things in your HTML message: `row[2]` and a link to `https://www.google.com/`. Your `links` variable becomes:

```
    var links = row[2] + '<a href="https://www.google.com/">Click here</a>';
```

If you e.g. want a newline between `row[2]` and the link, you can add `<br>`s:

```
    var links = row[2] + '<br /><a href="https://www.google.com/">Click here</a>';
```

(BTW: You might want to rename `links` to e.g. `htmlBody`. Using the `sendEmail(String,String,String,Object)` version of `sendEmail` to add the `htmlBody` we get this:

```
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, { htmlBody: links });
```

Comment: Thanks Sneep. But I'm trying to send automate emails from spreadsheet where C2 column has link with email address and name. Not familiar with HTML coding.  How do I write in javascript?

Comment: It worked so perfectly!! Thank you so much sneep!! I wouldn't have figure that out. Quick question, does the coding in JS goes horizontally only? I've long texts and multiple hyperlinks and had to scroll all way horizontally to end of line. Not an issue, I'm happy it is working :) Again thanks for your help.